# Efficiently read big csv file by parts using Dask

Tags: python, csv, dask, dask-dataframe

Now I'm reading big csv file using Dask and do some postprocessing on it (for example, do some math, then predict by some ML model and write results to Database).
Avoiding load all data in memory, I want to read by chunks of current size: read first chunk, predict, write, read 2nd chunk and etc.

I tried next solution using `skiprows` and `nrows`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
read_path = "medium.csv"

# Read by chunk
skiprows = 100000
nrows = 50000
res_df = dd.read_csv(read_path, skiprows=skiprows)
res_df = res_df.head(nrows)

print(res_df.shape)
print(res_df.head())
```

But I get error:

> ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of
>   data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to
>   `read_csv`/`read_table`

Also, as I understand, it will compute binary mask everytime ([False, False, ... , True, ...]) for all the data to find rows to load. How can we do it more efficient?
Maybe use some distributed or delayed functions from dask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dask dataframe will partition the data for you, you don't need to use `nrows/skip_rows`

```
df = dd.read_csv(filename)
```

If you want to pick out a particular partition then you could use the partitions accessor

```
part = df.partitions[i]
```

However, you might also want to apply your functions in parallel.

```
df.map_partitions(process).to_csv("data.*.csv")
```